# How to rebuild python youtube-dl from the source

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

At first I want to admit that I am a noob in python programming. but still somehow I have managed to figure out how to modify some python regular expressions as the extractor can get some extra data for me. Unfortunately I don't know how to build executable from the changed  source code. because I am using a PHP wrapper to use the youtube-dl ubuntu executable for **scraping** some data.

I have noticed there is a 6+ years old post on this in

[Python youtube-dl recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683518/python-youtube-dl-recompile)

but unfortunately the solution didn't provide the way to recompile or rebuild. I even haven't found how to rebuild in the official documentation for developer here in

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#developer-instructions

> Most users do not need to build youtube-dl and can download the builds
> or get them from their distribution.
>
> To run youtube-dl as a developer, you don't need to build anything
> either.

and at the end for open source contribution using git

> 11. Finally, create a pull request. We'll then review and merge it.

but couldn't find anything to build it locally to use locally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As documented in the [development instructions](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#developer-instructions), you can run youtube-dl interactively with

```
python -m youtube_dl
```

while the youtube-dl repository is in your `PYTHONPATH`, for example because your [cwd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) is the root of the youtube-dl repository.

For development, it's often easier to run the tests instead. Again, [as documented](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#developer-instructions), any of these work:

```
python -m unittest discover
python test/test_download.py
nosetests
```

If you're developing an extractor, you can run

```
python test/test_download.py TestDownload.test_YourExtractor
```

to just test your extractor.

If you actually want a youtube-dl binary, type

```
make
```

in the root directory of the youtube-dl repository. You will get a binary called `youtube-dl`.

Note that [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) works with *any* well-maintained software project, although some new-millennium hipster languages prefer to reinvent their own incompatible version.

Answer (score 3):

if you are in hurry and want to test you changes on youtube-dl file you can run it from it source python main file
`src_path/youtube_dl/__main__.py`
I use this to test running `youtube-dl` on Python3.8 instead of my system default 2.7.12 I just change `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3.8` and I ad soft link to the file `youtube_dl/__main__.py` on my system `/usr/local/sbin/` so you can test your changes immediately .